# PEAP-TLS for Linux

Tags: 802.1x

I would like to CLIENT  setup PEAP-TLS for my 802.1x environment. But unable to find any configuration for same

PEAP-TLS is available in Windows but not in Linux (At least in Ubuntu, Redhat family)

[This link](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) also do not provide any information about configuration of PEAP-TLS settings.

Is even Linux do support PEAP-TLS authentication method for wireless devices.

More infor about PEAP-TLS is at https://wiki.freeradius.org/protocol/EAP-PEAP#types_peap-eap-tls

Comment: Client or server?

Comment: I want to do Client setup

Comment: PEAP-TLS (or apparently more properly PEAP-EAP-TLS) seems to be a non-standard protocol from Microsoft. From [your own link](https://wiki.freeradius.org/protocol/EAP-PEAP#types_peap-eap-tls): "Since few third-party clients and servers support PEAP-EAP-TLS, users should probably avoid it unless they only intend to use Microsoft desktop clients and servers."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WiCD? Haven't used it in a while but I've seen  PEAP-TLS setup before.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicd

https://www.ironwifi.com/debian-wpa2-peap-eap-tls/